# Command to convert many images to one square image (not becoming a column or a row)

Tags: command-line, convert, image-processing, imagemagick, png

Is this really duplicate? I have not yet found it anywhere.

For example:

I have 4 PNG images: image1.png, image2.png, image3.png, image4.png.

Every one of them is 200x200 pixels.

I want to convert them to image1234.png.

image1234.png is 400x400 pixels, what consist of:

- image1.png is in the top-right.
- image2.png is in the top-left.
- image3.png is in the bottom-right.
- image4.png is in the bottom-left.

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use ImageMagick's `montage` utility. In your particular case the command would be:

```
montage image2.png image1.png image4.png image3.png \
        -geometry +2+2 1234.png
```

The order of the images is important as *in this example* you can see that the montage works:

```
Top Left --> Top Right --> Bottom Left --> Bottom Right
```

Thus the image names are matching *your desired order*. Lots more possibilities if you wish to *embellish* this command line but the command line I have given will accomplish your goal...

**References:**

- [ImageMagick v6 Examples -- Montage, Arrays of Images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) Some further examples on imagemagick's 'montage' command...

Comment: Sigh... the exasperation of researching an answer, testing it all out, writing it up, referencing it.... and then only tumbleweeds blowing across the abandoned question and answer both...

Comment: I'm familiar with that. I think some users just don't understand how Q/A sites work and think they are just forums, and I've seen several other, non-new users never vote on or accept any answers to their questions: I know because I kept answering a particular user who never provided any feedback, comments, votes, accepts, etc. Some users forget and some get what they want and never look back.

Comment: @llogan It would be nice if people appreciated the collaborative nature of Linux in general and I know (as I am sure you do as well) that this appreciation varies from distro to distro...

Comment: Are you still running Slackware, by the way? I'm still in Arch...haven't distro hopped in years.

Comment: @llogan I am, very happy there. Still lots of Ubuntu VMs though :)